# Can't extract text from an image with python OCR pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract texts from some images. It worked for hundreds of other images but in some cases it doesn't find any texts. In order to optimize the images for extraction phase, all images are converted to black and white. All of their backgrounds are white and others are black such as icons, texts etc.

For example it worked for below image and succesfully found 'Sleep Timer' text in the image. I'm not sure if it's relevant but size of the below image with 'Sleep Timer' text is 320 × 351

[image: Image with text 'Sleep Timer']
[image: Confidence levels and extracted texts]

But for the below image it doesn't find any text at all. Image size for this one is 161 × 320.

[image]
[image]

Since I couldn't find the reason, I tried to resize the image but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
from pytesseract import Output
import pytesseract
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('imagePath')

rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)

for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):

    text = results["text"][i]
    conf = int(results["conf"][i])

    print("Confidence: {}".format(conf))
    print("Text: {}".format(text))
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me I tested:

```
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string('../images/grmgrm.jfif'))
results = pytesseract.image_to_data('../images/grmgrm.jfif', output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
print(results)
```

> Are you getting an error? Show us the error you are getting.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I'm not getting any error. It outputs that confidence equals to -1 and there is no text as in the screenshot I added in the question. When I tried again with your code I also received same result which is: {'level': [1], 'page_num': [1], 'block_num': [0], 'par_num': [0], 'line_num': [0], 'word_num': [0], 'left': [0], 'top': [0], 'width': [161], 'height': [320], 'conf': ['-1'], 'text': ['']}